# Get backtrace for AOSP for static binary

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, gdb, android-source

From several reasons i have to compile my binary as a static.
I've also created a simple test app, with only two likes of code:

```
ALOGE(LOG_TAG, "Start");
ProcessState::self()->startThreadPool();
ALOGE(LOG_TAG, "startThreadPool");
IPCThreadState::self()->joinThreadPool();
ALOGE(LOG_TAG, "quit");
```

It seems that if i compile this small app as static, same as i need to compile my production app the **debuggerd** doesn't get triggered on SIGSEGV.

Also, the only lib that i can link statically in AOSP for backtrace is libunwind. ( CallStack, libcorkscrew and libbacktrace don't have static versions )

The problem with libunwind is that is get a crash when i call unw_step. A crash that i don't know how to investigate, because i don't have a stacktrace. ( http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/programmatic-access-to-the-call-stack-in-c/ )

So, any hints for getting the stacktrace of a static AOSP arm binary ?

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with the NDK? (Does your Android.mk set `LOCAL_SDK_VERSION`?)

Comment: No. It doesn't use NDK, is basic Android AOSP. It doesn't set LOCAL_SDK_VERSION in Android.mk

Answer (score 0):

How are you compiling libunwind? Are you using llvm-llvm sources or  the aosp external/libunwind sources?  Also what arch is this for?

libunwind is compiled in aosp as part of llvm-libc++abi if the target_arch_abi is armeabi or armeabi-v7a

from the Android.mk in $NDK/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi :

> ifneq (,$(filter armeabi%,$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)))
>     use_llvm_unwinder := true

If this is an arm project then there should also be a prebuilt static libunwind.a in $NDK/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi if I recall correctly. It might be worth trying the precompiled static libunwind.a from there

Comment: See the comment on the OP. This isn't using the NDK, so anything in the NDK isn't relevant here.

Comment: Aosp and NDK use the same sources for their libraries.  He wants a static backtrace. If you look in the AOSP  libbacktrace directory,  you can clearly see what the requirements would be (system/core/libbacktrace).